# Using values from mysql database to place marker on googlemaps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im trying to pull values from mysql database and use to draw a marker on the map but it doesnt seem to work, I've tested the database  connection and its working fine but i dont know what the problem is

```
<html>

 <?PHP
    include("config.php");
       $sql="SELECT * FROM lat long";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        $array=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);


        $Lat=$array['lat'];
        $Lng=$array['long'];


?>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }

      #select_route {width:20%;height:200px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">





    var map = "";
      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 31),
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }

      function addMarker() {

var LatLong= new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo lat ?> ,<?php echo lng ?>);
```

//Problem Lies here in passing the lat and long i suppose

```
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position:LatLong,

              });   
                marker.setMap(map);

               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<p style='color:blue'>UserInfo</p>" + '<button type="button">Navigate</button>' + '<IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="Left" SRC="testpic.png">' ,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 31), 
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

        };




        </script>
    <div id ="welcome" style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>Welcome to GoogleMaps  </h3>


</div>

  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();addMarker();">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:60%; height:80%"></div>
```

Comment: so you get an error? or what's wrong?

Comment: @MattBusche the map doesn't load

Comment: If the map doesn't load at all you should check the console for errors

Comment: @MattBusche Its saying that My Lat , Long variables are undefined, means my php variables are not read by the html code but how do i fix that

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I saw is that you are missing the $ sign before the php variables in the following line:

```
var LatLong= new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo lat ?> ,<?php echo lng ?>);
```

Also the variable names are not correct. You defined the variables as $Lng and $Lat starting with capital letters but in the above code you are using lowercase.

So change that line to:

```
var LatLong= new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $Lat ?> ,<?php echo $Lng ?>);
```

Besides this, you might have to adjust your query. It would make more sense if it was something along these lines:

"SELECT * FROM table_name" where table_name is the name of your table.

Finally, if it still does not work please post the javascript errors form your browser's console and the php error log to make it easier for me to see the errors.

Comment: I did the changes but still nothing is appearing,i'm using only 1 table for testing with 3 Columns (ID,Lat,Long)

Comment: Then change your query to something like "SELECT * FROM table_name" with your table name. Also, does it only have one row? Did you store only one marker in your table? The code you currently have can only work if you want to draw a single marker on the map.

Comment: Yes im only testing on 1 marker first before going through loops

Comment: Did you try to amend the query as I have indicated above?
If it still does not work after you amend the query, it would be helpful if you posted the php error log file to pastebin and post the link here so that I could see if there are any php errors. Also you could open up the web inspector on your browser and see if there are any errors in javascript in the console tab.

Comment: Yes I've changed the tablename, the console is saying that the lat,long variables im using are not defined also, im not familiar with how to log php errors.

Comment: Also make sure all your variable names are correct. I noticed that you defined the variables as $Lat and $Lng but used then as lat and lng with lowercase. Change them to uppercase $Lng and $Lat so that it matches with the actual variables that contain the coordinates. Re read my answer to see how that line should look.